# Grep command in java

Tags: java, grep

I am stuck with the `grep` command. I want to use grep to find out particular string in a file in java .

Program is compiled. But it does not return the line that contains the word navneet and just prints done.

I have tried out this following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
  public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String[] cmd = {"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\grep.exe","grep Navneet","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\gitconfig"} ;
    Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);    
    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream())); 
    String line;
    while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use java regex?

Comment: Conditions are using only grep command. not any pattern matching or regex

Comment: do this same grep from command line and show the results.

Comment: Got the solution  copied the file in the same directory and i got the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first String in the array that you pass to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` should be the full path to the command; and all other strings should be arguments.

So if you use

```
  String[] cmd = {"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\grep.exe",
       "grep Navneet","C:\\Users\\Admin\\type.gitconfig"} ;
```

you are calling grep with arguments `grep Navneet` and `C:\\Users\\Admin\\type.gitconfig`, meaning that it will search that file for the string `grep Navneet`, which it will not find. You wanted to use

```
  String[] cmd = {"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\grep.exe",
      "Navneet","C:\\Users\\Admin\\type.gitconfig"} ;
```

instead; or, if you want to find both `Navneet` and `navneet`

```
  String[] cmd = {"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\grep.exe",
      "-i", "Navneet","C:\\Users\\Admin\\type.gitconfig"} ;
```

Comment: I tried this out. but it doesnot work it just prints done only.

Comment: In that case you also have some other issue some other place. From the information you have provided I cannot tell what it is. You may want to follow @Krzysztof Cichocki’s suggestion: run the same grep command from  the command line (DOS prompt); edit your question and add the command and its output so we can compare and help identify any issues.

Answer (score 2):

In cmd (windows)
Output was as follows :

Command : C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin>grep "abc" C:\Users\Admin.gitconfig

Output : email: abc.kumar @yahoo.com
         name : abc.kumar

In java:

```
      import java.io.*;
      import java.io.BufferedReader;
      import java.io.IOException;

     public class Main {
            public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException{
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            String[] cmd = { "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\grep.exe", "@", "C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gitconfig"}; 
            Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);    
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream())); 
            String line;
                   while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
                         System.out.println(line);
                       }
            System.out.println("Done");
           } 
          }
```

Output:

```
        email = navneet.kumar@wct-inc.com
        Done
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have given the command to run (with full path) in the first `String` in the `cmd` array, don’t mention its name again in the next `String`. The second element (index 1) of the array should be just `"Navneet"` or `"navneet"`. This is other thing, you should decide for an uppercase or a lowercase `n`, it matters which you use.